# deploying a java web project from local mac computer to linux server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, deployment

I am wondering how I can quickly deploy the java dynamic web project that I built using eclipse on my mac to my Linode linux server? I already have a wordpress website running on the server and have also downloaded tomcat V6 and eclipse. Would I be able to manually copy the source, build and WebContent file contents? I would like to learn best practices for application deployment in the future but this project is very simple and I would like to be able to make it live as soon as possible. If you could also recommend any step by step tutorials I would really appreciate it.

thanks so much
Timnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider to build a WAR. Eclipse is just an IDE, it helps to develop, not to deploy.

Build your war (you can use maven/ant/build it from eclipse) - whatever you chose.

Once its ready your "deployment task" becomes a matter of moving a single file from MAC to linux server.

Comment: thanks. I have created a war file with eclipse. And have put it in the tomcat webapps folder. I am now trying to figure out how to

Comment: 1. propertly add a Context element

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/). See [how easily](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Starting+and+stopping+a+container) it can be integrated with Maven build. Here is an excellent [blog post](http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/244-automated-deployment-with-cargo-a-short-primer).

Comment: thanks a lot.I actually just created a WAR file using eclipse and that was all I had to do. But I'll look into Cargo